# Create relationship with a property inside owned Entity causes an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that has owned type and i want to create relationship with another entity but the foreign key property exist on the owned type example:-
This is my employee entity

```
public sealed class Employee : AuditedAggregateRoot
{
     public WorkInformation WorkInformation { get; private set; }
}
```

and it contains a value Object(Owned Type) called WorkInformation

```
public class WorkInformation : ValueObject<WorkInformation>
{
    private WorkInformation()
    {

    }
    public int? DepartmentId { get; private set; }
}
```

and i need to create relationship between Employee and Department

```
public class Department : AuditedAggregateRoot
{

}
```

and I use the following Fluent configuration to do that but i got an error

```
  builder.OwnsOne(e => e.WorkInformation)  

 //Add Employee Relations
   builder.HasOne<Department>()
   .WithMany()
   .IsRequired(false)
   .HasForeignKey(e => e.WorkInformation.DepartmentId);
```

and i got this error
[image]

if i move the DepartmentId to the owner entity, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Owned types (their properties, relationships etc.) cannot be configured via the owner type builder. Instead, use the `ReferenceOwnershipBuilder` returned by the `OwnsOne` method:

```
var workInfomationBuilder = builder.OwnsOne(e => e.WorkInformation);

//Add Employee Relations
workInfomationBuilder.HasOne<Department>()
    .WithMany()
    .IsRequired(false)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartmentId);
```

Comment: I have another minor issue, I changed a nullable column to a not-nullable one but i got an error when i try to update database

Comment: I got this error Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AllowSystemAccess', table 'DemoDb.Attendance.Employees'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Comment: That's normal when the table already contains records with `NULL` value. Add `Sql` command in your migration `Up` method to update the `NULL` values with something (`FALSE`, zero etc.) before the line that modifies the column.

Comment: I made something like that but it doesn't work             migrationBuilder.Sql(
                "UPDATE [Attendance].[Employees] SET AllowSystemAccess = 0 WHERE AllowSystemAccess = null", true);

Comment: I guess you should try `WHERE AllowSystemAccess is null`.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, i changed AllowSystemAccess = null to AllowSystemAccess is null

Comment: Thanks a lot but what about default values, Are these for new data only?

Comment: Yes, they are for new data only.