# How to configure a foreign key on an owned EF entity's property?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

**EF Core 3.0**

I have the following (simplified) entities in my domain:

```
class ApplicationUser {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

[Owned]
class Stamp {
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

class Activity {
    public Stamp Created { get; set; }
    public Stamp Modified { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

It's not particularly relevant, but it's worth mentioning that `ApplicationUser.UserName` is a non-primary, unique key. (`ApplicationUser` actually inherits from ASP.NET `IdentityUser`.)

I want to enforce that `Stamp.Username` is a foreign key referencing `ApplicationUser.UserName`.

If `Stamp` was a regular, *non-owned* entity, this would have set up that relationship:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Stamp.Username => ApplicationUser.UserName
    modelBuilder.Entity<Stamp>(e => {
        e.HasOne(s => s.User)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Stamp>(s => s.Username)
        .HasPrincipalKey<ApplicationUser>(u => u.UserName);
    });
    ...
}
```

When I try to create a migration (`dotnet ef migrations add`) I get an `InvalidOperationException` saying "The type 'Stamp' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists".

How to achieve what I'm trying to do, using Fluent API or otherwise?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) or [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/entity-framework/core/modeling/owned-entities.md) article could help you. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298739/create-relationship-with-a-property-inside-owned-entity-causes-an-error) could be one solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have been able to use the answer from the third link as a base for one possible solution. This comment is not the most appropriate place to describe that solution, so I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

One possible lead to explore : **WithOwner()** .HasForeignKey(...)

- More modern solution (EF [core] 6)
- Simplified solution (we use the user's Id as a foreign key
  instead of the user's Name, which is more standard!)

(Found in the help page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities )

```
//Please note that I wasn't 100% of the syntax when using 
// 'OwnsOne<Stamp>(builder => ...)' 
// instead of 
// 'OwnsOne(user => user.Stamp, builder => ...)'

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().OwnsOne<Stamp>(
    subBuilder =>
    {
        subBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ApplicationUserId");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should configure it in the owner using OwnsOne:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().OwnsOne(user => user.Stamp, stamp => 
{
    // configure your stamp 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution, likely not the most ellegant one. It is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298739/create-relationship-with-a-property-inside-owned-entity-causes-an-error) mentioned by ChW in the comments.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>(e => {
    e.OwnsOne(a => a.Created)
    .HasOne<ApplicationUser>()
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Stamp>(s => s.Username)
    .HasPrincipalKey<ApplicationUser>(u => u.UserName);
});
```

This sets up the required foreign key on a particular `Stamp` occurence (`Created`) for a particular owner entity (`Activity`).

A similar block of code would obviously need to be repeated for every other `Stamp` occurence (in this example, `Modified`) and for every other owner entity (`Activity` may not be the only one).

Btw, I also ended up removing the `Stamp.User` navigation property because EF has been using it to automatically create another foreign key that was (unwantedly) pointing to the `ApplicationUser.Id` property.