# Is there a way to create a one to many relationship from an owned EF entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to EF and I'm facing the following situation with my model.

I have the following entities:

```
public class ForwardingConstruct
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<FcPort>  FcPorts { get; set; }
  /// Other attributes

}

[Owned]
public class FcPort
{
  public virtual ICollection<LogicalTerminationPoint>  Ltps { get; set; }
  /// Other attributes

}

public class LogicalTerminationPoint
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  /// Other attributes

}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199833/how-to-configure-a-foreign-key-on-an-owned-ef-entitys-property) I know that it is posible to map a one-to-one relation from the owned entity, but my question is if it is posible to create a one-to-many reference from the same entity

**Edit:** Initially I forgot to mention that I'm using code-first approach and Entity Framework Core.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ForwardingConstruct
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  [InverseProperty("ForwardingConstruct")]
  public virtual ICollection<FcPort>  FcPorts { get; set; }
  /// Other attributes

}

[Owned]
public class FcPort
{
  [InverseProperty("FcPort")]
  public virtual ICollection<LogicalTerminationPoint>  Ltps { get; set; }
  public int ForwardingConstructId { get; set; }
  public virtual ForwardingConstruct ForwardingConstruct { get; set; }
  /// Other attributes

}

public class LogicalTerminationPoint
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int FcPortId { get; set; }
  public virtual FcPort FcPort { get; set; }

}
```

You should specify the foreign key in your tables. `LogicalTerminationPoint.FcPortId` is what tells to entity framework to create a relationship.
Then with the `InverseProperty` attribute you can specify which property EF can use to load the relevant children.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Béranger. I've forgot to mention that I'm using code first aproach and when I try your solution an "InvalidOperationException" with message "The entity type 'FcPort' cannot be added to the model because a weak entity type with the same name already exists." is thrown. Another question is that FCPort Entity initally has no primary key in my model.