# How use property from inner object (OwnsOne) as foreign key (HasOne-WithMany) in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm configured inner object by OwnsOne:

```
builder.OwnsOne(navigationExpression, b => {
     b.Property(x => x.Value);
     b.Property(x => x.Readonly);
});
```

and i want use property from this object (Value) as foreign key.
I'm try do it:

```
builder
    .HasOne(x => x.Issuer)
    .WithMany()
    .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.IssuerId.Value);
```

but i catch exception when try creating migration

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: The expression 'x => Convert(x.IssuerId.Value, Object)' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties or fields, use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty, t.MyField }'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')
```

Root object looks like this

```
public class ShareViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public OwnableValueViewModel<Guid> IssuerId { get; private set; }
    public OwnableValueViewModel<Guid?> RegistrationAuthorityId { get; private set; }

    /* .... other properties .... */
    
    public virtual ContractorViewModel Issuer { get; private set; }
    public virtual ContractorViewModel? RegistrationAuthority { get; private set; }
```

and OwnableValueViewModel

```
public record OwnableValueViewModel<T>
{
    public T? Value { get; init; }
    public bool Readonly { get; init; }
}
```

is there a way to configure this?

i found this answer:

[Create relationship with a property inside owned Entity causes an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298739/create-relationship-with-a-property-inside-owned-entity-causes-an-error)

but this not suitable for me because my navigation property placed in root object (ShareViewModel) but not in inner object (OwnableValueViewModel)